# Javascript Variable within jQuery string

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Can anyone help out with what im doing wrong here?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HapSB/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="usercurrentccbox">
    <div class="cardChoice">
        <label for="mastercard"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cct = "mastercard";
    //$('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice label[for=mastercard]').addClass("active");
        $('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice label[for="'+cct+'"').addClass("active");
});
```

**CSS**

```
    label{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:170px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

label.active{
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be missing a closing `]` in your selector.

```
// corrected
$('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice label[for="'+cct+'"]').addClass("active");
//                                                  ^ over here
```

Comment: Haha, my eyes just happened to land there first thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
        $('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice label[for="'+cct+'"]').addClass("active");
```

You just forgot the closing ]